# popup dialog is offset by too many pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am doing some modal popups but the dialog renders 200px to the left, and about 100px top of where it should.

updated jquery

```
DevicesRightClickActionsMenuController.prototype.showActionsMenu = function(event) {
    rightClicActionskMenuElement.css({
        top : $('.printer-context-node').offset().top + $('.printer-context-node').height() - $('.devices-right-click-menu-item').height() * 4 + 'px',
        left : $('.printer-context-node').offset().left + $('.printer-context-node').width() + 'px',
        position : 'absolute',
        zIndex : 1000
    });

DevicesRightClickMenuController.prototype.showRightClickMenu = function (xPosition, yPosition, theSerialNumber) {

serialNumber = theSerialNumber;

rightClickMenuElement.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: yPosition,
    left: xPosition,
    zIndex: 1000,
});
```

Comment: Maybe add some more code? How are the `yPos` and  `xPos` set?

Comment: How do I define that. I just figured that was built into the browser object. It's pulling in some numbers to offset if from somewhere, but I don't think it's anything that was coded in.

Comment: I have a feeling some other language or framework is involved except jQuery? Where did `DevicesRightClickMenuController` come from?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're using the wrong properties of the event to display the box, such as `pageX`/`pageY` instead of `clientX`/`clientY`. If you post some more code it will help narrow this down.

Comment: yeah I want it to be relative to another element. So if user scrolls webpage the dialog won't follow.

Comment: @ndesign11 I still don't see where you're getting the xPosition and yPosition variables from; the two functions in your code seem to be unrelated. Maybe you need to do something similar in the `showRightClickMenu` to what you're doing in the `showActionsMenu`?